# How do I read from a file using powershells Get-Content use join and put a space inbetween each line read

Tags: powershell

Currently I have the following code:

```
$memory = (get-content "c:\bat\logs\Results.txt") -join "  "
```

When I read in the contents of the file I was expecting there to be a space in between each line read in.  But currently it just jams everything together making it difficult to read.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you are expecting to see? I would imagine that the output from reading each line with a space between them would appear all jammed together and hard to read.

Comment: I usually join the lines of a file together with a linefeed: `-join "\`n"`. Reading the file is not a problem then.

Comment: Currently it looks like this␣28.76 - 7/16/2013 6:31:58 PM 28.77 - 7/16/2013 6:31:59 PM␣I want it to look like this␣28.76 - 7/16/2013 6:31:58 PM  28.77 - 7/16/2013 6:31:59 PM

Comment: Sorry this is my first time doing this
Currently it looks like this
28.76 - 7/16/2013 6:31:58 PM28.77 - 7/16/2013 6:31:59 PM
I want it to look like this
28.76 - 7/16/2013 6:31:58 PM 28.77 - 7/16/2013 6:31:59 PM

Comment: O.K. this is not working out.  The end of the line ends in either AM or PM then I want a couple of spaces and the next line.  Currently it would something like this PM28.77  I want it to be PM some spaces then 28.77

Comment: Please update your question with the actual and the desired output. Indent each line with 4 spaces, so it will be displayed as-is.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$memory = (gc .\tem.txt) -join "`n`n"
```